# Scrapy:meta['proxies'] or meta['proxy']?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm newbie at scrapy.I use a custom proxy in a scrapy spider，but I find if I use 
 request.meta["proxies"] , spider will work well,rather than using request.meta['proxy'].This is different from [this answer](https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000219743-using-a-custom-proxy-in-a-scrapy-spider)

This is part of my DEBUG messages, if I use request.meta['proxy'].

```
2018-09-07 15:48:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-09-07 15:48:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-07 15:48:45 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-09-07 15:49:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-07 15:50:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-07 15:51:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-07 15:51:45 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.example.com/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.example.com/robots.txt took longer than 180.0 seconds..
2018-09-07 15:52:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

My scrapy version

```
Scrapy       : 1.5.1
lxml         : 3.7.2.0
libxml2      : 2.9.4
cssselect    : 1.0.3
parsel       : 1.5.0
w3lib        : 1.19.0
Twisted      : 18.7.0
Python       : 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
pyOpenSSL    : 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018)
cryptography : 2.3
Platform     : Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
```

Update:I have solved the previous problem.But I don't konw why my meta['proxy'] is wrong,and my free proxy uses `requests.get('https://www.example.com/', proxies={"http": "http://{}".format(proxy)})`,it works well and returns `<Response [200]>`,so  what's wrong with my codes?

My settings:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware':135,
     'ip_proxy.middlewares.CustomProxyMiddleware':125
}
```

My spider:

```
 def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.example.com",callback=self.parse_first)
```

My CustomProxyMiddleware

```
class CustomProxyMiddleware(object):

  def __init__(self, settings):
      pass
  def process_request(self, request, spider):
      request.meta['proxy'] = "https://60.169.1.145:808"

  @classmethod
  def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
      return cls(crawler.settings)
```

Comment: Last snippet has bad indentation

Comment: What proxies are you using? I guess your server's IP is not entered into the proxy's authorized IPs section.

Answer (score 3):

To send request with a proxy server, you should use `meta['proxy']`. Looks like you have some issue with your proxy server, that's why it fails to scrape a page, causing timeout error. This may also be because you use a free proxy.

The reason your spider works with `meta['proxies']` is that setting this element does not affect anything and requests are send from your local IP.

Comment: You're right,but I have used`requests.get('https://https://www.example.com/', proxies={"http": "http://{}".format(proxy)})`.It returns `<Response [200]>`,means my free proxy is ok,so i'm confused.I'm not sure if there is a problem with my code,and I update my problem.